# Python-Tkinter: Trying to unpack a button with an if statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tkinter

I know there are better ways about this, but I cant figure out what's
wrong about this code, or at least, why it wont function the way I want it. Currently I made a simple test program to try my concept away from my
main code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
test = True
def click():
   global test
   print("working")
   test = False
button = Button(root, text="Hi", command=click)

if test:
   button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Everything runs fine but when I press the button all I get is the message "working" without the button going away.

Comment: Try `button.pack_forget()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code python checks if test is `True` and as it is, it packs the button and moves on. What you need to use is `<tkinter widget>.pack_forget()`. It removes the widget from the screen without destroying it. If you later call pack it should put it back in its original place. This is your code with the `pack_forget`:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def click():
   print("working")
   button.pack_forget()

button = Button(root, text="Hi", command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hmmm. I understand that but Im more curious as to why the loop doesn't stop the pack from happening. Since to my understanding, It loops through and packs that button constantly, and should it run through it but the if statement is false, the button shouldnt be packed no?

Comment: The loop only executes events and after scripts like when you do: `root.after(...)` or`button.bind(...)` or `Button(..., command=...)`. It doesn't go through your code again and again.

Comment: @SerkanSenyuz Close call, but you should understand that the code between `mainloop()` wont be run twice or many times like a loop, it will be just run once. So once it checks, its truthy and hence places the button. You change the value inside the function, but that doesn't effect the `if` outside the function. According to your logic, there would be many buttons as they keep repeating `button.pack()` many times, but it doesn't right?

Comment: @Cool Cloud Thats what im trying to understand because without ```mainloop()``` the code would only run once and the program would close almost instantly, thats why its called main "loop" cause it keeps it running continuously till you close it. But obviously it doesnt work so somewhere my logic is flawed in how the ```mainloop()``` works with the things in it (edit: Ty for all the help I know its a simple problem i just like understanding the full scope of why things go wrong)

Comment: @SerkanSenyuz It takes time, but `mainloop` is not a loop that runs your code, but `mainloop` is a loop that process events and checks them off if they are done from a _list_, so they keep on checking if the list of things to do(events to process?) are done, and based on that they continue, so this repetition? could be why its called a `mainloop`. Keep researching and you will figure it out soon.

Comment: By events @CoolCloud means key bindings, mouse clicks/movement and after scripts. So tkinter's `mainloop` is basically just: `while window isn't closed: handle events coming in`

Comment: Okay I think I have a good grasp on the concept then thank you so much